# What is the “-ine” word that pertains to sheep?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If *porcine* means pertaining to pigs, *bovine* pertaining to cows, and *caprine* pertaining to goats, what is the *-ine* word that denotes pertaining to sheep?

Comment: Perhaps *sheepish?*

Comment: This is pretty much [General Reference](http://bit.ly/Qj4i4h).

Comment: @T.E.D. No. It should be phrased: ... _is there_ an -ine word meaning 'pertaining to llamas'? And since 'llama' is not from a classical root ...

Comment: Why on earth do at least two people want to reopen this question? There's only one credible answer, and as @tchrist points out, it's remarkably easy to Google it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Ovine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ovine)* means *relating to or resembling sheep*.

Comment: I can but sheepishly observe that the famous boreal sheep-cattle more commonly known as musk oxen are **not *ovine*** nor *bovine* but believe-it-or-else *ovibovine* critters — whereas pronghorns are not actually *antilopine* but *antilocaprine* ones, and even the familiar prancing mountain goats are neither *ovine* nor *caprine* beasts at all but are *oreamnine* ones instead.

Comment: @tchrist this comment made my head hurt..

Comment: link is dead ...